# DinkToPDF working on local but not on the server

Tags: .net-core, dinktopdf

I am running a dotnet core 3.1 app, and I am using the DinkToPdf package for the necessary reports. When I try convert I get the following error when I click on the button that calls the conversion message.

```
An error occured while trying to generate the report.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load shared library 'libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibwkhtmltox: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libwkhtmltox' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibwkhtmltox: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at DinkToPdf.WkHtmlToXBindings.wkhtmltopdf_init(Int32 useGraphics)
   at DinkToPdf.PdfTools.Load()
   at DinkToPdf.BasicConverter.Convert(IDocument document)
   at DinkToPdf.SynchronizedConverter.<>n__0(IDocument document)
   at DinkToPdf.SynchronizedConverter.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Convert>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DinkToPdf.SynchronizedConverter.Invoke[TResult](Func`1 delegate)
   at DinkToPdf.SynchronizedConverter.Convert(IDocument document)
   at WEBelieve.Application.WebApi.Controllers.PortalController.AppReportController.GenerateReportFromHtmlStringV2(String html) in /App/Controllers/PortalController/AppReportController.cs:line 668
   at WEBelieve.Application.WebApi.Controllers.PortalController.AppReportController.GenerateJobDescriptionReport3(ReportViewModel reportViewModel) in /App/Controllers/PortalController/AppReportController.cs:line 615
```

My dockerfile is

```
# Build stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /App

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /App
COPY --from=build-env /App/out .

# Set environment variables
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

# Start the application
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WEBelieve.Application.WebApi.dll"]
```

I have the dll and all the other dependendencies in my root folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezu5R.png)

It works when I run the app locally (running the app through the dotnet run with all settings) but when I run it through the server, either from the docker container or on stage and production. When I look into the files on the docker server container, the libwkhtmltox.dll, libwkhtmltox.dylib, and libwkhtmltox.so are in the /App directory.

I tried to update the redistribution by adding the following to my docker file

```
# Install the latest version of Visual C++ Redistributable
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libc6 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and I still got the same error.

I have this is my .csproj file

```
<None Update="libwkhtmltox.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.dylib">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.so">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Do you have any suggestions I could try with this?

Comment: I would recommend doing as the error message suggests: In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable. You can do that either in your Dockerfile (`ENV LD_DEBUG=all`) or at runtime.

Comment: @AKX when I the ENV LD_DEBUG=all, I get the same error and no additional information

Comment: ```# Install libwkhtmltox dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        zlib1g \
        fontconfig \
        libfreetype6 \
        libx11-6 \
        libxext6 \
        libxrender1 \
        libjpeg62-turbo ```

I added this to my dockerfile and it worked and resolved the issue

Comment: You can self-answer your question with that :) Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Install libwkhtmltox dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        zlib1g \
        fontconfig \
        libfreetype6 \
        libx11-6 \
        libxext6 \
        libxrender1 \
        libjpeg62-turbo
```

This is what fixed the problem in the end

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**